# file.json data to be used in d3js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, arrays

This is the json file that I have generated from GA(FILE NAME-->tracking.json)

```
  ["51b59c162de88", [["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]
    ["51b59c1b4f52f", [["star-speak", 0.0, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]
    ["51b59c2bdd5c5", [["signature", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011]]]
    ["51b59c10ca18f", [["parties", 0.0, 0.017]]]
    ["51b59c15913b6", [["parties", 0.0, 0.011]]]
    ["51b59c2635997", [["fashion", 0.002, 0.006], ["parties", 0.0037, 0.011], ["royal-challenge", 0.002, 0.006]]]
```

I want to use this json file data in my d3js to be appended in a table.
How can an external file data be used in a code?I cannot start with my project untill I solve this?
Need some help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d3.json("test.json", function(json) {

});
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json---->link has some vital info,you have to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for the [d3.json() method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json). Once you load your file, you can do whatever you want with the JSON as you would normally in the callback.